# Jquery Add Extra Row in HTML But Data Not Submited in POST

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using jquery to add extra row in html. Following code work for me, but when i tried to submit form, extra row fields missing in &_POST array. Please check code and let me know, how to fix this issue..

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var cnt = 2;

$("#anc_add").click(function(){
$('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="title[]" value=""></td><td><input type="text" name="body[]" value=""></td><td><input type="text" name="sound_url[]" value=""></td><td><input type="text" name="id[]" value=""></td></tr>');
cnt++;
});

$("#anc_rem").click(function(){
$('#tbl1 tr:last-child').remove();
});

});

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
   <table id="tbl1" width="700" height="0" border="0" style="margin-top:20px">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th width="220" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col" height="35"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">Title</span></th>
    <th width="220" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col" height="35"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">Body</span></th>
    <th width="220" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col" height="35"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">ID</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><i class="icon-plus"></i><a style="color:black" href="javascript:void(0);" id='anc_add'>Add Row</a><i style="margin-left:30px" class="icon-minus"></i><a style="color:black" href="javascript:void(0);" id='anc_rem'>Remove Row</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="title[]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="body[]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="url[]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

   </tbody>
   </table>
```

I've two other table on top of this table

Something like that

```
<table class="table">
</table>

<table width="700" border="0" style="size:10px;">
</table>
```

When i removed these, problem fixed, how i fix this issue?

**HTML form**

```
 <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" id="SubmitForm" />
```

Comment: Can we see your whole code? Are the new form elements within `<form></form>`

Comment: if you check me question, i have updated with proper reason of three tables in html. Add row table is last one, when i remove top 2 table and submit form, its working for me, please let me know, how to bypass top 2 forms,

Comment: I see about the 3 tables, but I don't see the actual `<form>` tag in your code. It would be helpful to see it altogether. Based on the code you've posted so far, there is no problem.

Comment: form details updated in questions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code in JsFiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/ku9mL/1/.

Its working for dynamic rows.

```
    $('#SubmitForm').click(function(e){

    var postData = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
    $(postData).each(function(i, field){ 
        alert(field.name+"="+field.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, its add new row in in form fields... i received all fields alert instead of new added fields .. and new add field still missing in POST array

Comment: Please check my updated question, its conflict because of two other tables in html. please let me know, i pass top two table?

Answer (score 1):

Your final HTML markup should look like this:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table class="table">
</table>

<table width="700" border="0" style="size:10px;">
</table>

<table id="tbl1" width="700" height="0" border="0" style="margin-top:20px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="220" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col" height="35"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">Title</span></th>
<th width="220" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col" height="35"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">Body</span></th>
<th width="220" bgcolor="#999999" scope="col" height="35"><span style="color: #FFFFFF">ID</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><i class="icon-plus"></i><a style="color:black" href="javascript:void(0);" id='anc_add'>Add Row</a><i style="margin-left:30px" class="icon-minus"></i><a style="color:black" href="javascript:void(0);" id='anc_rem'>Remove Row</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="title[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="body[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="url[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" id="SubmitForm" />

</form>
```